# how to unlock screen when booted from usb?

Tags: boot, usb, login-screen, testdisk

i installed ubuntu 13.10 in the installation process i lost all data.
i booted from the usb and took the help of testdisk.

sudo apt-get install testdisk

sudo testdisk

After finding all the partition the screen is locked now.
how to unlock it?

Comment: Is it possible to recover data on the same harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

Leave the password field blank and press enter.

Comment: i tried but not responding.

Comment: thaks for reply.

Comment: Are you able to use the short-cut CTRL+ALT+F1 to get to a terminal?

Comment: yes,i am able to get it.

Comment: run `sudo service lightdm restart` then switch back to regular desktop with CTRL+ALT+F7

Comment: system got restarted.again i will have to find all the partition.

Comment: how to unlock screen if booted from usb.